# commerce kickstart 2 easy way to disable products from view

Tags: commerce

hi I'm having a hard time managing my stock using the kickstart 2 module. I have product display with multiple product variants. I do not use stock level, as I sell online and other places so I update manually when a product isn't available anymore. I will however want to use the variant and product again in the future.

So I thought nice and easy I'll just use the Disable button, located via `admin/commerce/products` then press the `Quick Edit` button select `Disable` and `Save`.

This kind of works as the product now shows `Product Not Available` on the purchase screen. however what I'd ideally like is the product not to show up at all, or to say not available on the broader search list.

Additionally I **unpublished** the content, which is a lot more convoluted to achieve. And this had the annoyance of being extremely hard to find again. I had to create a new view just to look for unpublished Product Display types.

Comment: Your search results will probably be for nodes (not products), so un-publishing the content is the best way to go. Maybe install Inline Entity Form so you can manage the product's status from inside the node form too, less UI to trawl through that way. A view showing currently un-published nodes sounds like a good way of managing it; you only need to create that view once

Comment: fair point. I'd love to find a way I could Unpublish/Publish a product from a view generated list. Inline Entity appears to be in use for the Product, but not sure if it can do what I need.